# AFP and Time Machine stopped working on QNAP HS-251+

Tags: macos, nas, qnap, timemachine

Time Machine and AFP have stopped working. I think it may have happened at the firmware update before last but cannot confirm that.
I have an HS-251+ w/ firmware version 4.3.6.0959
I have macOS 10.14.5 and QNAP.

When I try connect to the NAS using Finder (**Go > Connect to Server > "afp://NAS1" > Connect**) I receive an error: "There was a problem connecting to the server NAS1. The server may not exist or is not available. ...etc"
I can no longer see the server in Finder side panel, but if I click Network I can see it only if I turn on Windows Networking.
On a linux workstation I can see all the NFS mounts fine.

Time Machine can no longer find NAS1 to back up either.

I am completely stumped as to how to fix this.

Thanks

Bryon

Comment: Would be a better idea to ask the same on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QNAP Support confirmed this is a bug. 
I was able to confirm that it only happens if you create additional shares - then time Machine stops working. You delete the shares and time machine can see the Nas again.